# Nested PHP conditional statement structure issue

Tags: php

I am using Google Distance Matrix to calculate the distance between two locations for a taxi website. I need to test a condition to ascertain whether the one of the locations is a London airport and if so return a message rather than the calculating the cost of the trip.

It worked perfectly yesterday and then today ... the code has gone biserk. It is only returning the message if pick-up and drop off locations are both airports but if only one is, it is calculating the cost for the full distance which defeats my purpose. Below is the code structure and I am wondering whether I am using the wrong nested conditional syntax at line 39 when I start the strpos() test  ....

```
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])):
        $origin = urlencode($_POST['origin']);
        $destination = urlencode($_POST['destination']);

        // Insert encoded url variables
        $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$origin&destinations=$destination&mode=driving&keyy={API KEY}";
        $json = file_get_contents($url); // get the data from Google Maps API

        $status = $result['rows'][0]['elements'][0]['status'];

    if (status is OK):
        // Calculate the distance
        $status = ...;
        $DistanceMetres = .....;
        $Distance = .....; // converted to yards

        // Calculate the Day Rate
        ....

        // Calculate the Night Rate
        ....

        // Calculate the Sunday Rate
        ....

        // Calculate the Christmas & NYE Rate
        ....

        // Set up variables for pick-up & drop-off locations
        $toairport = $result['destination_addresses'][0];
        $fromairport= $result['origin_addresses'][0];

        if (distance is the minimum distance) {
        echo the minimum cost of the trip

        } else { //ie if the distance is more than the minimum distance

            // Check to see if pick-up or drop-off destination is an airport
            if (strpos($toairport, 'Heathrow') || strpos($toairport, 'Gatwick') || strpos($toairport, 'London Luton') || strpos($toairport, 'London City Airport') || strpos($fromairport, 'Heathrow') || strpos($fromairport, 'Gatwick') || strpos($fromairport, 'London Luton') || strpos($fromairport, 'London City Airport') === false) {
                echo the cost of the trip

            // But if at least one location is an airport
            } else {
            echo a message saying a special flat rate is available for airport transfers
            }
        }

    else:
    echo that status is not okay
    endif;

else:

display input form

 endif;
```

Comment: Why does the last `strpos()` in your if statement need to be `=== false` and the others don't? Am I missing something...?

Also, if the string is found in position 0 of your string, then `if(0)` will never be true..

Comment: Surely you want to check for Airports BEFORE you do a minimum distance calculation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to implement the check as a function. For example

```
/**
 * Check if the location is an airport.
 *
 * @param string $location
 * @return bool
 */
function isAirport($location)
{
    $airportList = ['Heathrow', 'Gatwick', 'London Luton', 'London City Airport'];
    foreach ($airportList as $airport) {
        if (strpos($location, $airport) !== false) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Note that we compare `strpos` result with `false` using `!==` operator because `strpos` might return zero which is `==` to `false`.

Next, internal check might look like this

```
if (isAirport($toairport) || isAirport($fromairport)) {
    echo 'a message saying a special flat rate is available for airport transfers'.PHP_EOL;
} else {
    echo 'the cost of the trip'.PHP_EOL;
}
```

Note that we check that either `$toairport` are $fromairport` variables are airport locations. I guess this is what you want the script to do.

When we use function like this it makes significantly easy to read the script and understand what is it doing. Also it makes it easier to modify the script by adding new location or improving the logic. For example we might want to make the check case insensitive.

Comment: Victor, that is absolutely brilliant, simple, clean, easy to understand and works perfectly!